# scala Stream.takeWhile

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, fold, lazy-sequences

I am implementing `takeWhile` method of trait `Stream` via `foldRight`.
My `foldRight` is following:

```
trait Stream[+A] {
  def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B =
    uncons.map(t => {
      f(t._1, t._2.foldRight(z)(f))
    }).getOrElse(z)
}
```

My `takeWhile` is

```
def takeWhile(p: A => Boolean): Stream[A] =
  uncons.filter(t => p(t._1)).map(t => Stream.cons(t._1, t._2.takeWhile(p))).getOrElse(Stream.empty)
```

But I want it to be implemented via `foldRight`. Here is the code:

```
def takeWhileViaFoldRight(p: A => Boolean): Stream[A] =
  foldRight(Stream.empty)((x, acc) => {
    if (p(x)) Stream.cons(x, acc) else Stream.empty
  })
```

But my `x` in `Stream.cons` expression is underlined red with the following error: `type mismatch; found : x.type (with underlying type A) required: Nothing`. I guess this is because `foldRight` start value is `Stream.empty` -- with no type `A` indicated hence considered to be `Nothing`. If this is the case -- how can I tell `foldRight` that its return value is `A`, not `Nothing`? If not -- what's the problem then?

Comment: foldRight(Stream.empty[A]).....

Comment: Hmm, I thought type parameters can be used in method declaration, not its call... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The courtesy of [jdevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741404/jdevelop)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057771/scala-stream-takewhile#comment52014442_32057771):

```
foldRight(Stream.empty[A])
```

will do the thing.